# hyper-v detection using C Programming

Tags: c#, c, windows, hyper-v

I need to be able to detect whether Hyper-V is enabled and running on a system or not and based on this information perform a particular function. How can I do this using C Programming language?

Please advise.

Thanks!

Ben

Comment: Your question mentions only C but you tagged both C *and* C#. Which is it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You could take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to have a global idea of how this site works, and read the [advice on how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in the help center to see what questions are on-topic and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a clue. You can check it's process if it is running or not. There will be a function in C which will give you a list of running processes in your system.

Best,